# Optional parameters in Meteor router

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I have a path in Meteor

```
path: '/my-url/:groupId?',
```

I have added the question mark to indicate that sometimes `groupId` is not used. In `data` I check whether the group id is set with `this.params.hasOwnProperty('groupId')` but I have come across that sometimes the router thinks groupId is set even if it isn't (don't know why) but the value is `undefined`.

Therefore, I tried

```
console.log(this.params.hasOwnProperty('groupId'));
console.log('groupId' in this.params);
console.log(this.params.groupId);
```

and they evaluate to

```
> true
> true
> undefined
```

So I guess `hasOwnProperty` is not the best way to check whether `groupId` is set since it doesn't check for undefined values.

What will be a better way to check this? Why does `hasOwnProperty` evaluate to true even if my url is `/my-url`?

Comment: have you found other solution for this

Answer (score 1):

I think you've already answered yourself on your question. I have same problem and my check is:

```
if (this.params.groupId) {
} else {
}
```

*This is not yet confirmed*, but I think as long as you provide `:groupId`, you're already have that in params, regardless it exists or not.